# @ApiOperation vs @ApiResponse in Swagger

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-2.0

`@ApiOperation` has an attribute `response` to which we can pass the Response type. In `@ApiResponse` also we have an attribute `response` to which we can pass the Response type. So What is the exact difference between them?

Answer (score 7):

You must specify the *success* response in `@ApiOperation` while you can specify ALL possible response objects in `@ApiResponse`.

`@ApiResponse` is used wrapped inside `@ApiResponses` and generally used to specify error codes and exceptional cases like `Resource Not Found` or `Bad Request` etc. You can also specify `success` response, but it is not mandatory to do so, as the success response is anyway mentioned in `@ApiOperation`.

Comment: Is it mandatory to specify success response in `@ApiOperation`?

Comment: If your API returns any response entity under successful case, it must be mentioned as `response=` in @apiOperation. If you do not specify, although nothing bad will happen, swagger will not be able to show the response structure. But that's the whole point of using swagger: to document APIs.

Answer (score 0):

The usage of `@ApiOperation` and `@ApiResponse` is a bit different. With @ApiOperation you can specify the return type of the REST method using `response`. With @ApiResponse you can send back other information like HTTP code, user defined message and other headers if any you want to return

Comment: are those the only difference?